# How to draw planar graphs of that satisfy Euler's formula

Tags: planar-graphs

The full question is:

> In each case, give the values of $r$, $e$, or $v$ assuming that the graph is planar. Then draw a connected planar graph with the property, if possible.

The values I was given were 6 vertices all of degree 4 and another problem with the given values 5 regions and 10 edges.

According to Euler's formula $r = e-v+2$, there should be 12 edges and 8 regions for the first problem and 7 vertices for the second problem. However I can only come up with a graph that has 7 regions for the first problem and 6 vertices in the second one. What am I doing wrong and how should I tackle drawing these problems?

[image]

Comment: Don't forget the unbounded face.

Comment: I just started this course in college but can I get a brief explanation of what the unbounded face is?

Comment: @ShawnLi It is the part of the paper that is outside of the picture you drew.

Comment: Your first graph has 8 regions, your second graph has 6 regions. You're forgetting to count the big outer region.

Comment: I see, so one of the regions that are counted is external of the graph. Somewhat confusing but I think I understand

Comment: @ShawnLi Exactly!  It might be useful to know that the formula comes from looking at faces, edges, and vertices on polyhedra.  Planar graphs correspond (roughly) to things that are homeomorphic to a sphere, such as a cube.  Remove one face of the cube, then flatten it out---you get a planar graph.  The face that you removed is the unbounded face of the graph.